# Location track items must be given as pairs of comma separated lat/longs Twitter4J Scala

Tags: scala, twitter, twitter4j

I am trying to filter tweets by user locations. I am using Twitter4J in Scala for that. But every time I get an error

```
Parameter not accepted with the role. 406:Returned by the Search API when an invalid format is specified in the request.
Returned by the Streaming API when one or more of the parameters are not suitable for the resource. The track parameter, for example, would throw this error if:
The track keyword is too long or too short.
The bounding box specified is invalid.
No predicates defined for filtered resource, for example, neither track nor follow parameter defined.
Follow userid cannot be read.
Location track items must be given as pairs of comma separated lat/longs: [Ljava.lang.String;@48d1de0f
```

Here is my code:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {    
    val twitterStream = TwitterStreamFilters.configureTwitterStream()
        val counter = new Counter
        twitterStream.addListener(counter)
        TwitterStreamFilters.filterTwitterStreamByLocation(twitterStream, Array(-122.75,36.8,-121.75,37.8))
        TwitterStreamFilters.closeTwitterStream(twitterStream)
    }
```

I took the location for San Francisco from [this link](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/guides/basic-stream-parameters).
So why this twitter stream doesn't work? I would be grateful for any advice.

The method for locations:

```
  def filterTwitterStreamByLocation(twitterStream: TwitterStream, coordinates: Array[Double]) = {
    twitterStream.filter(new FilterQuery().locations(coordinates))
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried to pass the lat/longs as String?

Comment: @perbellinio I have updated the question. I use standard location method on filter query and it takes Array[Double] as parameter

Comment: could paste the entire error message?

Comment: Sure, I have added all the lines of the message to the question

Comment: According to the documentation (http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/FilterQuery.html#locations) you have to pass a 2d array so Array[Array[Double]]. This is a link on how to create 2d arrays in Scala: https://alvinalexander.com/source-code/scala/how-create-and-use-multi-dimensional-arrays-2d-3d-etc-scala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So following my comment above, this should solve your issue:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {    
    val twitterStream = TwitterStreamFilters.configureTwitterStream()
        val counter = new Counter
        twitterStream.addListener(counter)
        TwitterStreamFilters.filterTwitterStreamByLocation(twitterStream, Array(Array(-122.75,36.8,-121.75,37.8)))
        TwitterStreamFilters.closeTwitterStream(twitterStream)
    }

def filterTwitterStreamByLocation(twitterStream: TwitterStream, coordinates: Array[Array[Double]]) = {
    twitterStream.filter(new FilterQuery().locations(coordinates))
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked only after I have changed twitter4j dependency version in sbt from 4.0.6 to 3.0.6.